Run solana rpc node got error "connection timed out"
I am trying to run a solana rpc node of mainnet. I followed the aiticle how-to-run-a-solana-rpc-node due to I did not find the way of how to run a rpc node on mainnet on the solana's official website. Here is my validatory.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
export RUST_LOG=error

solana-validator \
    --identity /var/solana/data/config/validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --no-voting \
    --ledger /var/solana/data/ledger \
    --accounts /var/solana/accounts \
    --log /home/r630/solana-rpc.log \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 127.0.0.1 \
    --private-rpc \
        --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --init-complete-file /var/solana/data/init-completed \
    --limit-ledger-size

execute the script
> ./validator.sh

check the log file
> tail -f solana-rpc.log
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 103.97.176.73:8001, connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 184.173.136.86:8001, connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 209.95.56.60:8001, connection timed out
get_cluster_shred_version failed: 67.228.235.91:8001, connection timed out

env
>solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.21 (src:818807a5; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs)

>uname -a
Linux r630-PowerEdge-R630 6.5.0-18-generic #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 11:40:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I wonder how to solve this problem.

I think it would be worthwhile to check the documentations below
https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/guides/validator-start
https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/setup-an-rpc-node
